# select and update the database after clicking an item on android using JDBC

Tags: android

how to select and update the data on the database using JDBC after clicking an item on the spinner.I want that the current value on the DB will be incremented by 1 after clicking an item on the spinner.Here s my code below,it doesn't update the value on the db

```
    public void updateVotes() {
            String name  = pres.getSelectedItem().toString();//TO GET THE LIST THAT IS BEING SELECTED FROM THE SPINNER
            String vote="";
            int s;
    try {
            Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Votes FROM tcandidates     where lastname = '"+name+"'");//SELECT THE CURRENT VALUE FROM     THE DB TO UPDATE
    while (rs.next()) {
            vote = rs.getString("Votes");//TO GET THE VALUE AS A STRING
                      }
            s = Integer.valueOf(vote);//PARSE THE VALUE TO INT TO INCREMENT IT BY ONE
            s=+1;
            String sql = "Update tcandidates set Votes=? where lastname =         '"+name+"'";//query for updating the value on the database
             PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
             statement.setString(1,s+"");//inserting the vl
             int rowUpdated = statement.executeUpdate();
             if (rowUpdated > 0) {
             Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Voted             Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
              } catch (SQLException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
              }
```

Comment: this solves your issue http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jdbc/sample-jdbc-preparedstatement-sql-update

Comment: what problem you are facing ?

Comment: after an item on the spinner , the data won't be updated..